# disable pop up blocker in android webview

Tags: android, webview, popup

I am working on an app and a large part of it is having a series of useful links which open in a webview. I have the links working, but at least one of the sites requires pop up blocker to be disabled. I can not find anyway to disable pop up blocker for webview. Is there no way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use the `setSupportMultipleWindows` in the `WebSettings`

> Tell the WebView whether it supports multiple windows.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setSupportMultipleWindows(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setSupportMultipleWindows%28boolean%29)

You can do something like this:

```
WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();  
settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
```

Comment: That sounded like it might do the trick but I am still getting the same error. The error reads:"This warning is to let you know that your pop-up blocker has prevented the system from opening up the application. We recommend you modify your browser settings to allow pop-ups from this site to prevent this warning in the future."

Comment: Try also setting the javascript properties to true `settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`
`settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but still no luck.